# node-soap result is deep nested object instead of plain result

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, soap

I use node-soap to request a SOAP-API. But the result is not as I expect it.
It works as expected if I request the same using PHP (all api samples are in php).
But my application/service is written in JavaScript (ExpressJS).

My request code is very simple:

```
var url = '...wsdl';
var args = {
    Params: JSON.stringify({
      User: '...',
      AuthType: 'session',
      AuthData: '...',
      RequestType: 'get_mailaccounts',
      RequestParams: []
    })
};
soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
    client.Api(args, function(err, result, rawResponse, soapHeader, rawRequest) {
      console.log(util.inspect(result, {showHidden: false, depth: null}));
    });
});
```

The result looks like this:

```
{
  "return": {
    "attributes": {
      "xsi:type": "ns2:Map"
    },
    "item": [
      {
        "key": {
          "$value": "Request",
          "attributes": {
            "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
          }
        },
        "value": {
          "attributes": {
            "xsi:type": "ns2:Map"
          },
          "item": [
            {
              "key": {
                "$value": "RequestTime",
                "attributes": {
                  "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                }
              },
              "value": {
                "$value": "1540823916",
                "attributes": {
                  "xsi:type": "xsd:int"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "key": {
                "$value": "RequestType",
                "attributes": {
                  "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                }
              },
              "value": {
                "$value": "get_mailaccounts",
                "attributes": {
                  "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "key": {
                "$value": "RequestParams",
                "attributes": {
                  "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                }
              },
              "value": {
                "attributes": {
                  "SOAP-ENC:arrayType": "xsd:ur-type[0]",
                  "xsi:type": "SOAP-ENC:Array"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "key": {
          "$value": "Response",
          "attributes": {
            "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
          }
        },
        "value": {
          "attributes": {
            "xsi:type": "ns2:Map"
          },
          "item": [
            {
              "key": {
                "$value": "FloodDelay",
                "attributes": {
                  "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                }
              },
              "value": {
                "$value": "0.5",
                "attributes": {
                  "xsi:type": "xsd:float"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "key": {
                "$value": "ReturnString",
                "attributes": {
                  "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                }
              },
              "value": {
                "$value": "TRUE",
                "attributes": {
                  "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "key": {
                "$value": "ReturnInfo",
                "attributes": {
                  "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                }
              },
              "value": {
                "attributes": {
                  "SOAP-ENC:arrayType": "ns2:Map[1]",
                  "xsi:type": "SOAP-ENC:Array"
                },
                "item": {
                  "attributes": {
                    "xsi:type": "ns2:Map"
                  },
                  "item": [
                    {
                      "key": {
                        "$value": "mail_login",
                        "attributes": {
                          "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                        }
                      },
                      "value": {
                        "$value": "xxxxxxx",
                        "attributes": {
                          "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": {
                        "$value": "mail_password",
                        "attributes": {
                          "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                        }
                      },
                      "value": {
                        "$value": "xxxxxxx",
                        "attributes": {
                          "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": {
                        "$value": "mail_adresses",
                        "attributes": {
                          "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                        }
                      },
                      "value": {
                        "$value": "xx@xx.de",
                        "attributes": {
                          "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The information the object contains is ok and what I expect. But why is it so weird nested? The result object I get from the mentioned PHP code looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "KasFloodDelay": 0.5,
        "ReturnString": "TRUE",
        "ReturnInfo": [
            {
                "mail_login": "xxxxxxx",
                "mail_password": "xxxxxxx",
                "mail_adresses": "xxxxxxx",
                ...
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is what I want.

Comment: could it be the way `util.inspect() ` parses it? What happens if you just console log result?

Comment: @delboy1978uk thanks, but I tried that. Then I get the same result, just not that deep: `result { return:
   { attributes: { 'xsi:type': 'ns2:Map' },
     item: [ [Object], [Object] ] } }`